# How do I use regex to match a pattern in .NET?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, regex

I am trying to build an Ajax RegularExpressionValidator to look for strings in a TextBox that are missing a dash (-) surrounded by characters.

User is suppose to enter values like so

AA-BBBBB

1-223344

Basically, any number of alpha-numeric chars surrounding a dash (-). Could contain multiple dashes, but I only care that it has at least one dash.

Thanks for your time.

Be kind with your laughter as I don't know what I am doing with RegEx, but it would appear to be the best way to tackle this.

Based on what I read, i tried this

`^[\S-\S]+$`

and even gave this a shot
`^[*-*]+$`

Comment: Can you have `AA-223344` and `1-BBBBB`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these:

```
^\w+-\w+$               // Alphanumeric and underscore
^[A-Za-z\d]+-[A-Za-z\d]+$     // Only alphanumeric
^[A-Za-z\d]+-[A-Za-z\d]+$     // Only alphanumeric upper case

// Only alpha OR only numeric (upper case) (Exclusive Or)
^([A-Z]+-[A-Z]+)|(\d+-\d+)$
```

[See test in Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/zRTTOsATA0).

Comment: Ah, so I was close. I thought that \S would match any char other then a space, blank, etc. Thanks

Comment: `[A-z]` will include all the characters between `Z` and `a`.. including things like `[\]^_`

Comment: I believe that I understand ......... don't know why I was trying to make this more complex then it needed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
 #  ^[^\W_]+-+[^\W_]+$

 ^          # Beginning of string
 [^\W_]+    # 1 or more alphanum
 -+         # 1 or more dash '-'
 [^\W_]+    # 1 or more alphanum
 $          # End of string
```